# 5V Regulator causing component damage

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

[image]Im using a 5V OKI Murata DC-DC device to power an Arduino UNO R3 and a 4 channel 433MHz receiver. Ive got a 24V DC source which is a bench PSU at the moment. But ive noticed that every so often the RF module would fail as it heats up. Im not sure why but the regulator outputs a steady 4.95V. 
The regulator is the 5V 1.5A OKI-78SR device which has a current draw of about 8-10mA applied to it with my components.

The only thing I can think of is that there might be oscillation or a voltage spike here or there that causes damage to the RF receiver. The data sheet available [OKI Datasheet from here](https://power.murata.com/data/power/oki-78sr.pdf) says that i dont really need external components. 
I chose the OKI device as i didnt fancy the idea of reducing up to 24V down to 5V using a standard regualtor as it would likely heat up and go boom.
So far I have had two RF modules fail, im using the QIACHIP RF module available [RF Datasheet from here](https://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/QIACHIP-433mhz-RX-480-RF-Relay-Receiver-Decoder-Module-Wireless-4-CH-Output-With-Learning-Button/2780158_32843881195.html) 
I have the wiring correct and I am only using D0 and D1 of the RF module and these are being read by the Arduino digital inputs directly.

Are there any external components i should use on the input or output of the DC-DC to prevent this odd issue? It got me confused at this point.
Im also driving a 2 channel relay board from the DC-DCs output. 
The issue did occur when i didnt have it connected but it may be chance, initially i thought it may be floating voltages >5.5V (the maximum input of my RF device) due to the low current draw of <10mA. I may be wrong.

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it!
Thank you guys

UPDATE: ive added a schematic just to try and clear things up, if it helps
Ive also included a [link to the relay board i am using](https://www.ebay.ie/itm/DC-5V-12V-24V-30A-1-Channel-2-Channel-Relay-Module-Board-High-Low-Trigger-O2L5/352452866606?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=621790513984&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649) for reference.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE!  What makes you think that the DC-DC converter is causing your RF modules to fail?  Are these permanent failures, or does the RF module start working again once it cools down?  More information on the components/connections involved would help as well

Comment: Your cause of *failure* is likely something else, but there is also a substantial risk of switching mode power supply reducing the weak signal performance of your radio receiver.  Also beware the bench supply, some cheaper ones have been caught doing extremely rude things on turn on/off or enable/disable.

Comment: hi, thanks for the welcome! the rf modules seem  to heat up and keep doing so and they dont recover as they can longer be programmed using the button. i.e. the pairing button doesnt allow remore fobs to be programmed and the buttons on the fob dont respond anymore. the IC that heats up is  located under the clock on the receiver, it can be seen in the pictures in the link in my post.

Comment: i use a power supply from RS components which outputs fixed voltages but it might still be a bit iffy when switching on and off

Answer (score 1):

Components usually die from overvotlage, when the voltage gets too high for the absolute maximum ratings section.

I'll bet this is the culprit of the circuit problems:

> It got me confused at this point. Im also driving a 2 channel relay
>   board from the DC-DCs output.

Relays without a flyback diode can cause an overvoltage condition momentarily, make sure the relays have a flyback diode.

Check the votlage rails with an oscillosope while operating the relays to make sure the voltage does not exceed 5.2 (or whatever the max voltage is for all parts tied to that rail.

Make sure you fuse the input to the DC DC converter

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. its got a 2A fuse on the input as recomended by the manufacturer. The relays are on a module and are opto isolated.

Comment: Could you supply a schematic, there is a tool if you edit your question

Comment: Hi laptop2d, thank you for your response!

Comment: Hi laptop2d, thank you for your response! I just created a schematic and added it to my original post. I dont know if my 24V voltage divider has anything to do with my issues. with a supply of 24v i get just under 3V out which is within the arduino 5V ADC range. I plan on running this on a battery so voltage spikes shouldn't be a problem. I hope this helps you. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As stated in page 19 and 20 of the data sheet, you should use input and output filtering capacitors. I know on the first page it says they aren't required, but they're almost always a good idea.

Although, I'm going to highly doubt that the regulator is the case of the component failure.

Comment: yes, i just saw that and was thinking 22uF @ 50v on the input and a 47uF at 25v or 50v on the output. it might be sufficient, hopefully

Answer (score 1):

DC-DC converters always have high output voltage ripple. It may damage your IC. You may easily try to add output capacitors to suppress it. MAX output capacitance is defined as 3300uF in datasheet pg.8.

If it doesn't work well,
think about using DC-DC converter and regulator together. DC-DC converter output noise will be suppressed by the regulator according to the regulator PSRR. 
Also, there is no heating problem anymore.

There is 2 option for this.
1 : find another dc-dc converter to step down from 24V to ~7-8V  and then use regulator to supply rf module.
2 : as I see, rf module also work with 3V3. Use dc-dc converter to step down from 24V to 5V and then use another 3V3 output regulator to supply rf module.